# Home insider installation not requested - Windows 11

Tags: installation, virus

"windows 11 home insider preview evaluation copie" - i see this message on my desktop after being recommended to restart because there were updates to do. I did not agree to the installation of nothing new. They were going to be just updates.
So, is it bad? how do i take it out?

I never saw this message before and, honestly, I am worried because also lately my laptop has been behaving a bit bizarre. I already was thinking that my system could have a virus, but I checked (with antivirus and scanning) and all nothing detected.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance